# Two RMI registries on the same PC, NotBoundException

Tags: java, rmi

Scenario:
I'm implementing an RMI example between 2 PCs where the Controller PC queries the Agent PC for information. The agent PC may run Xen or KVM , hence the implementations of the queries differ(Reason for using RMI).
On the Agent's side I'm running 2 RMI registries bound to two different ports. When the same example is carried out with just 1 Registry on the agent's side, everything works fine.

Here is my code:
Controller. java(contains main() on controller's side):

```
public class Controller {

NetworkDiscovery n;
public static int discoveryInterval=2000;
static public PM pmlist;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,NotBoundException, `   MalformedURLException, RemoteException {

pmOperations pm=(pmOperations)Naming.lookup("rmi://Agent_IP/RMIService1");
boolean l= pm.CreateVM("apple3","/var/lib/libvirt/images",1,200);
System.out.println(l);

vmOperations vm=(vmOperations)Naming.lookup("rmi://Agent_IP/RMIService2");
boolean ShutdownVM = vm.ShutdownVM("apple1");
System.out.println(ShutdownVM);
//other code
}
```

pmOperations.java(on controller's side)(on the agent's side, it has the same defn with implementation code inside function)

```
public interface pmOperations extends java.rmi.Remote{
    public boolean CreateVM(String vmName,String imgSrc, int allotCPU, int allotMem )
    throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

vmOperations.java(on controller's side)(on the agent's side, it has the same defn with implementation code inside function)

```
public interface vmOperations extends java.rmi.Remote{
    boolean ChangeVMParam(String vmName,String paramName,String paramValue)
    throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

Agent.java

```
public class Agent {

Agent() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException{
    Registry RMIService1 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

    Registry RMIService2 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4478);

        vmOperations vmOp = new kvmVM();
        pmOperations pmOp = new kvmPM();

      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RMIService1", pmOp);
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:4478/RMIService2", vmOp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException, LibvirtException {

        System.out.println("Inside main ");
        new Agent();
        //other code
}
}
```

Error I get while running above code on controller's side-no error on agent side:

> Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: RMIService2
>           at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:106)
>           at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
>           at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
>           at package1.Controller.main(Controller.java:43)

Thanks!

Comment: Why? You don't need two Registries on the same host. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: @EJP- The two functions I'm using above- CreateVM and ShutdownVM are placed in two different interfaces which implement RemoteInterface. That's how We've designed it. 
Even then, is it wrong to start 2 RMI registries on a PC?

Comment: It's pointless. Just another thing to go wrong. Just register the object in the same registry twice with two different names. Your current problem may be due to looking up the wrong registry for example: if you only had one you couldn't make that mistake.

Comment: @EJP- So you're asking me to change the code on agent's side to:
Registry RMIService1 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4478);

    Registry RMIService2 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4478);

        vmOperations vmOp = new kvmVM();
        pmOperations pmOp = new kvmPM();

      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:4478/RMIService1", pmOp);
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:4478/RMIService2", vmOp);
Right? THis gives me an error that ObjID is already in use

Comment: That changed code still creates two registries. Not what I suggested at all. But NB you would certainly have got that exception with the original code too. You can't create two Registries in the same JVM. And you don't need to create two instances of the remote object either. Just bind the same one twice.

Comment: Multiple Registries on the same host? O_O

Comment: @fireshadow52 I don't know what O_O means. Your point?

Comment: @EJP- Maybe Im asking a dumb question. I'm just a newbie.Sorry.

Comment: @EJP My point is that I'm confused about what is wrong with creating two Registries on the same host.

Comment: @fireshadow52 I didn't say it's wrong, I said it's pointless. You can't do it within the same JVM and there isn't any point that I can see using two JVMs, e.g. rmiregistry x 2, unless maybe you have some severe codebase conflicts, and it would be better all round to actually solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create two Registries in the same JVM.
You don't need two Registries in the same host.
You don't need to create two instances of the remote object.

Just create *one* Registry, *one* remote object, and bind it to the Registry twice, once with each name. You don't really need to bind it twice either really either. There's a lot of pointless duplication in this design.

Comment: @EJP- Please tell me if I'm right-
1. I should remove RMIservice2 , bind RMIService1 to both pmOp and vmOp on the agent's side 
Registry RMIService1 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        vmOperations vmOp = new kvmVM();
        pmOperations pmOp = new kvmPM();
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RMIService1", pmOp);
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RMIService1", vmOp);
}
and make similar changes on controller's side (I'm getting a proxy error)
2.OR create a parent interface with 2 children(vmOperations and pmOperations) and make the parent extend Remoteinterface, right?

Comment: @EJP- I'm getting a proxy error if I use the above method 1.Please help me.

Comment: @EJP- This error on controller's side:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to package1.pmOperations
        at package1.Controller.main(Controller.java:36)

Comment: @P Ramesh Ah OK so you do need the two remote objects, my mistake.

Comment: @EJP- Yeah, that's how I'm supposed to implement it :/ (it's been designed that way by another person so that all PM related operations come under pmOperations and vice versa for VM related operations

Comment: @EJP- I guess I'll have to make just one interface then. If you come up with any idea, do tell me. Thanks!

Comment: @P Ramesh You can leave the objects and interfaces part of it alone. But you have to just use one Registry.

Comment: I'm suing just one registry ie Registry RMIService1 = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        vmOperations vmOp = new kvmVM();
        pmOperations pmOp = new kvmPM();
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RMIService1", pmOp);
      Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RMIService1", vmOp);
Which gives me this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to package1.pmOperations
        at package1.Controller.main(Controller.java:36)

Comment: @P Ramesh now you're trying to use the same bind name for both remote objects.

Comment: @EJP-I'm sorry but I really don't get you. Can you please tell me how it's to be implemented in the code(I've tried out all possibilities I could think of)

Comment: @P Ramesh Computer programming isn't about trying all possibilities. It is about understanding and analysing what you are doing. In this case you are binding both remote objects with the same name. That means two things: when you lookup the first one you will get the second one, and a ClassCastException, and when you lookup the second one you will get another exception. If you can't see that, you need to read your own code and make an effort to understand it, until you do see it..

Comment: @EJP- thanks for being so patient. I got the idea and it works fine.