# Getting NotBoundException when Client lookup to server

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to run the rmi tutorial on oracles' website. I am able to run the server, but I receive an error running the client. The error I receive when try to run the client is a NotBoundException exception. How do I fix this error?

Below is the code and exception

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: Server
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:234)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:133)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:468)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:298)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:380)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:123)
    at rmi.Client.main(Client.java:13)
```

I use Server and Client with different project at Port 1212

here is Server

```
package De_1;

import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAOImpl();
        r.bind("Server", productDAO);
    }
}
```

and here is Client

```
package rmi;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1212);
        ProductDAO productDAO = (ProductDAO) r.lookup("Server");

        System.out.println("Hay nhap");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String command = sc.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(command);
            String request = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println(request);
            switch (request) {
                case "HELLO": {
                    productDAO.addProduct();
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking up the wrong Registry. You're binding to the one you started on port 1099 but yoiu're looking up one on port 1212. Surprising that there is even one there. If there wasn't you would have got a `ConnectException`.

Comment: I start server on by command
`rmiregistry 1212 &` but it throw this exception in lookup

Comment: But you're then starting another Registry on `Registry.REGISTRY_PORT`, and the value of `Registry.REGISTRY_PORT` is 1099, and that's the Registry you're binding to. You don't need your `rmiregistry 1212` command at all.

Comment: Duplicate of [Two RMI Registries on the same PC, NotBoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735112/two-rmi-registries-on-the-same-pc-notboundexception?rq=1).